# how to remove particular repeated string from large string

Tags: javascript

I have one string, I want to remove some repeated part from string using ajax or javascritp.

The string is -

```
    1-16-15-master=1232_2-34-33-master=1232_3-33-23-master=1236
```

Above string is connect using underscore (_) sign. means above string include 3 string. I want to remove -master=122....

The '-master=' is default but after equal sign(=) number will change. So how to remove '-master=n...' from above string.

Comment: You want output like this: 1-16-15=1232_2-34-33=1232_3-33-23=1236 ?

Comment: not php .. its using jquery or js

Comment: I want output like -                                                 1-16-15_2-34-33_3-33-23

Answer (score 4):

```
var s = "1-16-15-master=1232_2-34-33-master=1232_3-33-23-master=1236";
console.log(s.replace(/-master=\d+/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a replace function with a greedy `/-master=\d+/` regex :

**PHP**

```
$input = "1-16-15-master=1232_2-34-33-master=1232_3-33-23-master=1236";
$output = preg_replace('/-master=\d+/', '', $input);

echo $output; // 1-16-15_2-34-33_3-33-23
```

**JS**

```
var input = "1-16-15-master=1232_2-34-33-master=1232_3-33-23-master=1236";
var output = input.replace(/-master=\d+/g, '');

console.log(output); // 1-16-15_2-34-33_3-33-23
```

Comment: The PHP tag should not have been used by the OP and was removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = "1-16-15-master=1232_2-34-33-master=1232_3-33-23-master=1236";
str = str.replace(/-master=/g,'=');
```